# Echo array index with comparative operators - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Given an array such as...

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = "blue" or "red" or "green" or "brown";
```

How would I use this to evaluate an if statement and echo it? for instance...

```
If ($ans1 = $array[0]) {
   echo "correct answer $array[0]";  // this should display "blue or red 
                                     //               or green or brown"
}
```

Comment: `$array` isn't what you think it is. It'd only contain the value `blue`. See [this demo](http://3v4l.org/TJN0n).

Comment: What's the problem here? The echo? You're also assigning instead of comparing. Use == for compares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use another array statement instead of the `or` operators which fulfill a totally different use-case:

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = array("blue", "red", "green", "brown");

// new syntax
$array[0] = ["blue", "red", "green", "brown"];
```

Then, in your outputting code:

```
echo "Correct answers: " . implode(" or ", $array[0]);
```

---

By the way, using `if ($ans1 = $array[0]) {` is **incorrect**! There is a missing equal sign:

```
if ($ans1 =  $array[0]) {
// --------^
if ($ans1 == $array[0]) {
```

`

Comment: @ComFreek: Also, I don't see the need for the multi-dimensional array here. You could just do [this](http://3v4l.org/6ubQQ).

Comment: @AmalMurali What about multiple questions? I usually don't change the data structure the OP has given in the question. (By the way, this doesn't justify a downvote in my opinion).

Comment: @ComFreek: I've removed the downvote but I think it'll be a good idea to include that in your answer. :)

Comment: I'm with @ComFreek I tend to think that OP is using a multi-dim array for a specific reason so stick with it.

Comment: @AmalMurali Sorry if I do not fully understand you, but the current data structure is actually the right one, providing that the OP has multiple questions. Sample: http://3v4l.org/U6X3e

Comment: @ComFreek: Anyway, since the OP accepted your answer, I think you're right - `+1`. But it might help if you add that explanation (if you prefer) in your answer so that it may help future visitors too.